# Android Virtual Device - Black screen and I've tried everything

Tags: android, virtual, android-virtual-device

This is a fresh install of Android Studios on Ubuntu 16.04.

I just get a black screen on the AVD every time. I been reading related threads tried the following:

- Changing to software gpu
- many different device profiles
- many different andoid system image versions
- wiping the user data for the device
- both x86 and arm images
- both the x86 and x64 emulators
- various amount of RAM for each device
- running with no skins

And more things that I can't recall right now.

The qemu process does start and consume quite a bit of CPU time, but nothing ever happens. No error messages either. Just hangs up.

My i5 processor does have virtualization support as well.

Before I break down and install windows to get this working, is there anything else I can try?

EDIT: The kernel does boot but enters an infinite loop repeating these messages:

```
[  117.942709] init: property_set("ro.boottime.wificond", "117942505853") failed: property already set

[  117.964867] init: starting service 'netd'...

[  117.965726] init: property_set("ro.boottime.netd", "117965553859") failed: property already set

[  117.974155] init: Created socket '/dev/socket/netd', mode 660, user 0, group 1000

[  117.975147] init: Created socket '/dev/socket/dnsproxyd', mode 660, user 0, group 3003

[  117.976174] init: Created socket '/dev/socket/mdns', mode 660, user 0, group 1000

[  117.977136] init: Created socket '/dev/socket/fwmarkd', mode 660, user 0, group 3003

[  117.989764] init: starting service 'zygote'...

[  118.000458] init: property_set("ro.boottime.zygote", "118000275846") 
failed: property already set

[  118.010134] init: no such service 'wpa_supplicant'

[  118.011053] init: Created socket '/dev/socket/zygote', mode 660, user 0, group 1000

[  122.394998] init: starting service 'surfaceflinger'...

[  122.396072] init: property_set("ro.boottime.surfaceflinger", "122395874175") failed: property already set

[  122.397299] init: Failed to bind socket 'pdx/system/vr/display/client': No such file or directory

[  122.398293] init: Failed to bind socket 'pdx/system/vr/display/manager': No such file or directory

[  122.399281] init: Failed to bind socket 'pdx/system/vr/display/vsync': No such file or directory

[  122.454693] healthd: battery l=100 v=5000 t=25.0 h=2 st=2 chg=a

[  122.486518] init: Service 'surfaceflinger' (pid 2847) killed by signal 6

[  122.487278] init: Sending signal 9 to service 'surfaceflinger' (pid 2847) process group...

[  122.488207] init: Successfully killed process cgroup uid 1000 pid 2847 in 0ms

[  122.489051] init: Sending signal 9 to service 'zygote' (pid 2815) process group...

[  122.498945] init: Successfully killed process cgroup uid 0 pid 2815 in 9ms

[  122.500398] init: Service 'zygote' (pid 2815) killed by signal 9

[  122.501398] init: Unable to open '/sys/android_power/request_state': No such file or directory

[  122.502779] init: Unable to write to '/sys/power/state': Invalid argument

[  122.503869] init: Sending signal 9 to service 'audioserver' (pid 2804) process group...

[  122.511295] init: Successfully killed process cgroup uid 1041 pid 2804 in 6ms

[  122.513308] init: Sending signal 9 to service 'cameraserver' (pid 2805) process group...

[  122.521445] init: Successfully killed process cgroup uid 1047 pid 2805 in 6ms

[  122.522669] init: Sending signal 9 to service 'media' (pid 2806) process group...

[  122.530468] init: Successfully killed process cgroup uid 1013 pid 2806 in 6ms

[  122.531675] init: Sending signal 9 to service 'netd' (pid 2814) process group...

[  122.539229] init: Successfully killed process cgroup uid 0 pid 2814 in 6ms

[  122.540805] init: Sending signal 9 to service 'wificond' (pid 2812) process 
group...

[  122.548870] init: Successfully killed process cgroup uid 1010 pid 2812 in 6ms

[  122.550996] init: Service 'audioserver' (pid 2804) killed by signal 9

[  122.552127] init: Sending signal 9 to service 'audio-hal-2-0' (pid 2807) process group...

[  122.559507] init: Successfully killed process cgroup uid 1041 pid 2807 in 6ms

[  122.561085] init: Service 'cameraserver' (pid 2805) killed by signal 9

[  122.562292] init: Service 'media' (pid 2806) killed by signal 9

[  122.563413] init: Service 'audio-hal-2-0' (pid 2807) killed by signal 9

[  122.564576] init: Service 'wificond' (pid 2812) killed by signal 9

[  122.565608] init: Service 'netd' (pid 2814) killed by signal 9

[  122.566673] init: Untracked pid 2858 exited with status 0

[  122.567567] init: Untracked pid 2817 killed by signal 9

[  122.568495] init: Untracked pid 2818 killed by signal 9

[  122.569442] init: processing action (init.svc.zygote=stopping) from 
(/system/etc/init/bootstat.rc:62)

[  122.578092] init: starting service 'audioserver'...

[  122.579401] init: property_set("ro.boottime.audioserver", "122579133766") failed: property already set

[  122.580660] init: starting service 'cameraserver'...

[  122.581377] init: property_set("ro.boottime.cameraserver", "122581249935") failed: property already set

[  122.582626] init: starting service 'media'...

[  122.583276] init: property_set("ro.boottime.media", "122583158219") failed: property already set

[  122.600086] init: couldn't write 2865 to /dev/cpuset/camera-daemon/tasks: No such file or directory

[  122.870197] init: starting service 'audio-hal-2-0'...

[  122.871067] init: property_set("ro.boottime.audio-hal-2-0", "122870905135") failed: property already set

[  122.920102] binder: 2864:2864 transaction failed 29189/-22, size 32-0 line 2936

[  122.921441] binder: 2864:2864 transaction failed 29189/-22, size 32-0 line 2936

[  122.942631] init: starting service 'wificond'...

[  122.943501] init: property_set("ro.boottime.wificond", "122943322473") failed: property already set

[  122.965669] init: starting service 'netd'...

[  122.966468] init: property_set("ro.boottime.netd", "122966306126") failed: property already set

[  122.971540] init: Created socket '/dev/socket/netd', mode 660, user 0, group 1000

[  122.972491] init: Created socket '/dev/socket/dnsproxyd', mode 660, user 0, group 3003

[  122.973386] init: Created socket '/dev/socket/mdns', mode 660, user 0, group 1000

[  122.974265] init: Created socket '/dev/socket/fwmarkd', mode 660, user 0, group 3003

[  123.002232] init: no such service 'wpa_supplicant'

[  123.002902] init: starting service 'zygote'...

[  123.003738] init: property_set("ro.boottime.zygote", "123003531647") failed: property already set

[  123.009193] init: Created socket '/dev/socket/zygote', mode 660, user 0, group 1000
```

Comment: From the terminal  go to \users\yourUsername\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\platform-tools\ and then execute adb devices and see if any devices show up.  Of course any devices that aren't real but virtual.  You should see something like 24829849284928         device

Comment: Within that directry I have "adb" and "android-tools-adb". When I execute "./adb devices" I get "List of devices attached" and nothing listed there at all.

Comment: What is the api level for the avd?

Comment: The testing above was using 27. I have since learned that this is a beta version and that's likely the problem? But many of the lower versions don't work either because I can't disable hardware graphics acceleration, which I need to do because I run the real nvidia drivers. So I finally tried API 22 which does work but isn't great for developing, being so old.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like the kernel is not booting.

try to run this command to see some messages.

```
cd /path/to/your/sdk/emulator-official
./emulator -show-kernel -avd your-avd-name
```

Please try the following command to use guest gpu:

```
./emulator -show-kernel -gpu guest -avd your-avd-name
```

Comment: Thank you so much, that really shines a light on this. The kernel is booting but it enters an infinite loop. I will add the messages from the kernel to the post.

Answer (score 0):

from: \users\yourUsername\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\platform-tools‌​\ 
execute following command:

emulator -avd yourAvdDeviceName -netdelay none -netspeed full

Comment: Thank you for the help. Unfortunately it behaves the same, looping and printing those messages. It is also now saying that the emulator is out of date, despite just downloading this yesterday and following the update procedure:   - Start Android Studio
 - Select menu "Tools > Android > SDK Manager"
 - Click "SDK Tools" tab
 - Check "Android Emulator" checkbox
 - Click "OK"