# AVD showing black screen tried every single step

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native, android-studio, android-virtual-device

AVD is not starting up on my gaming laptop hp omen tried every single step i want that my device show a proper device

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please add more information about what steps you have a tried to solve this issue. Also confirm that this is not a duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47233405/android-virtual-device-black-screen-and-ive-tried-everything) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62525892/android-studios-emulator-with-black-screen) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39305466/android-emulator-stuck-with-black-screen) on a similar problem

Answer (score 0):

1. First basic thing you can check is emulator device is not power off, try powering on by clicking power button on device.
2. Next thing you can do is delete that device and download another device in emulator using device manager.
3. One more important thing is try downloading new device with older version like Oreo, Nougat, because they're stable version sometimes new versions have bugs that can cause issues
4. If issue still persist you can try uninstalling android studio before that I suggest you try to run your app on physical device i.e. your phone

Comment: i do everything installed other devices older versions

Comment: Then try 4th option, reinstall the android studio

Comment: installed may be 9-10 times